# Комбинация LEFT и INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

Есть у меня три таблицы `t1`, `t2`, `t3`. Записи из каждой таблицы могут ссылаться на предыдущую

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  t1_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE t3 (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  t2_id INT
);

INSERT INTO t1 (id) VALUES (1);

INSERT INTO t2 (id, t1_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO t2 (id, t1_id) VALUES (2, NULL);

INSERT INTO t3 (id, t2_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO t3 (id, t2_id) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO t3 (id, t2_id) VALUES (3, NULL);
```

Мне нужно вытащить записи из всех трех таблиц с двумя условиями

1. Записей в `t2` может не существовать
2. Если в `t2` есть записи, то выбираются только те, которые ссылаются на `t1`

Т.е. должна получиться такая выборка

| t3.id | t2.id | t1.id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | null | null |

Попробовал такой запрос

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  t3
  LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t3.t2_id = t2.id)
  JOIN t1 ON (t2.t1_id = t1.id)
```

но получил только одну запись

| t3.id | t2.id | t1.id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

Моя задача решается таким запросом

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  t3
  LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t3.t2_id = t2.id)
  LEFT JOIN t1 ON (t2.t1_id = t1.id)
WHERE
  t2.id IS NULL OR
  t2.t1_id IS NOT NULL
```

но мне не понятно, как же работает JOIN в комбинации с LEFT JOIN? К чему джойнятся записи? Или проблема в том, что записи не могут приджойниться к NULL, а порядок что к чему джойнится не определен?

Ссылка на [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bGu6jLyW8BJPfuynN7VuLR/0)

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` выводи все записи из левой таблицы и совпавшие записи из правой , `JOIN` выводит только записи успешно присоединеные записи из обоих таблиц, получается что в последнем присоединении совпал только id=1 c предыдущей выборкой, остальные записи не выводятся

Comment: Как-то логика получения такого результата из таких данных непонятна от слова "совсем". И она никак не соотносится с показанными "условиями".

Comment: @ipatev_nn Почему обоих? Запрос `FROM t3 JOIN t2 LEFT JOIN t1` отработает как и ожидается. Вначале построится пересечение t3 и t2, а потом по мере возможности добавится t1. А здесь мне нужно к t3 присоединить пересечение t2 и t1

Comment: @Akina не понял комментария. Какая логика непонятна и что не соотносится?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Так как вопрос _не как?, а почему?_, то не совсем понятно, что вам непонятно. В этом запросе`FROM t3 LEFT JOIN t2 JOIN t1` я без сомнений ожидаю только одну запись, Но вы пишете: _но получил только одну запись_, то есть ожидаете что-то другое. Что вы ожидаете, и почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t3.id t3_id,
  t2.id t2_id,
  t1.id t1_id
FROM
  t3
  LEFT JOIN (t2 INNER JOIN t1 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id) ON t3.t2_id = t2.id
```

Выполняем `LEFT JOIN` между T3 и результатом `INNER JOIN`а T2 и T1

Comment: Вот именно это я искал. Т.е. джойны можно группировать?

Comment: Да, можно. На всех известных мне СУБД: Microsoft SQL. Interbase/Firebird, MySQL

Answer (score -1):

Сильно похоже на

```
SELECT t3.id,t2.id,t1.id
FROM t3
JOIN t2 ON (t3.t2_id = t2.id)
JOIN t1 ON (t2.t1_id = t1.id)
UNION ALL
SELECT t3.id,NULL,NULL
FROM t3
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t3.t2_id = t2.id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Да этот запрос решает задачу. Как и мой и как еще парочка. Но вопрос был о работе пары LEFT JOIN -> JOIN. Т.е. вопрос не **как?**, а **почему?**

Comment: И, кстати, этот вариант хуже, если предварительно нужно будет отфильтровать записи из t3. Тогда нужно будет писать два идентичных WHERE